# Python list comprehension list - a good way to pick up a max

Tags: python, vector, numpy, list-comprehension

I am writting a function that should find out first the dimension of space where input vectors are living. The orientation of vectors is unknown, so that it can be 1*ndim or ndim*1. I would like to find a beautiful one liner to do so. I tried this one, but this is not proper syntax:

```
 ndim = [max(n,p) for n,p in (n,p) = np.shape(X) if min(n,p) = 1]
```

btw, I also want to quickly check whether the little dimension is effectively 1.

Any idea?

Comment: How about `assert min(X.shape) == 1; ndim = max(X.shape)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the following fixes the errors in your expression:

```
ndim = [max(n,p) for n,p in [np.shape(X)] if min(n,p) == 1]
```

To quickly check if the smallest dimension is `1`, use:

```
min(*np.shape(x)) == 1
```